# Segmentation fault in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++

I have an abstract class `MyClass` that has a const attribute `my_attr`. Each subclass should initialize this attribute as they see fit, by overriding the pure virtual method `init_my_attr`.

The problem is that this results in a segmentation fault.

```
// MyClass.h

class MyClass : public MyParentClass
{
public:
    MyClass(...);

protected:
    virtual vector<int> init_my_attr() const = 0;

private:
    const vector<int> my_attr;
}


// MyClass.cpp

MyClass::MyClass(...) : MyParentClass(...), my_attr(this->init_my_attr())
{

}
```

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call a virtual function in the constructor.  Base classes are constructed first so there is no derived class that you can call the virtual function on.

That said, there is a really easy solution.  Add a constructor to `MyClass` that takes a `std::vector` and initializes `my_attr` with it.  Then your derived class can call that constructor and pass it a vector that it created.